# How to extract specific key values from list in Python?

Tags: python

My head is almost exploding. How can I can extract specific key values from list of objects?

List:

```
sensors = [
    {'id': 1, 'values': [3, 100, 21, 77, 3]},
    {'id': 2, 'values': []}
]
```

I want extract id's. Like this: `{"sensor_ids":[1,2]}`

I found couple of working examples, but they were not for the list. I got this working with one object, but not with the list.

My code (removed all earlier try solutions which none of working):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import json
import ast


app = FastAPI()

sensors = [
    {'id': 1, 'values': [3, 100, 21, 77, 3]},
    {'id': 2, 'values': []}
]

@app.get('/sensors')
def get_courses(): 

    str_lista_objekteista = []
    for s in sensors:
        
        ## HERE, ANY IDEAS ##
        
        str_lista_objekteista.append()
      

    return {'senros_ids': str_lista_objekteista}
```

Comment: `[x['id'] for x in sensors]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the key is always id, why not something like:

```
return {'sensor_ids': [x['id'] for x in sensors]}
```

Comment: Thanks! Again, too easy solution. I always think too difficult way.

Comment: My pleasure. It's not that difficult to overlook, when many other languages insist you iterate through the array and take actions accordingly. I have to say this is one of the things I really like about Python.